# position text and image in sidenavigation

Tags: css

How do i position a centered text or logo (picture 2) at the bottom of the viewport similar to a footer? When the dropdownmenue (picture 3) opens the logo or text should move accordingly to the new height.

So the div below point 5 should dynamically change its height or get out of site in case.

I tried several solutions i googled prior but somehow all did not work like i wanted it to be.

[image]

Comment: So you have a list of lists and a logo on the bottom, when you open one of the lists everything should be pushed downward, is that it ? Also where's your code ?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/ found this site with the problem i have, will try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of the footer, then you could use min-height, absolute positioning and padding-bottom. However I'm going to assume the more difficult case in which you don't know the height.

```
<style>
    * {box-sizing:border-box;}
    .wrapper {min-height:100vh;display:flex;flex-direction:column;}
    .main {flex:1 0 auto;}
    .footer {background-color:yellow;padding:16px;font-weight:bold;flex:0 0 auto;}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <h1>
            Main
        </h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquet, nibh id placerat viverra, justo purus semper dolor, at lacinia eros mauris eu libero. In finibus a urna dapibus tempus. Aenean ipsum urna, tempor at lectus non, blandit feugiat quam. Donec sed ante orci. Integer laoreet est erat, a feugiat leo posuere sed. Mauris sit amet metus finibus, dapibus nunc ut, molestie erat. Nullam rhoncus sagittis lacus id finibus. Etiam sollicitudin nibh dui, a mollis nisl pharetra vitae. Suspendisse nec laoreet ipsum. Fusce sit amet tempor sem. Vestibulum consequat est in nisl aliquam ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat.
        </p>        
        <p>
            Sed vulputate nisl ac est eleifend bibendum. Nullam cursus at ex sit amet dignissim. Sed blandit pretium venenatis. Phasellus at ullamcorper nibh. Aenean nec lectus semper, efficitur diam in, luctus nisi. Phasellus in ligula congue, cursus nunc et, luctus mi. Suspendisse a leo luctus, molestie elit sed, venenatis sem. Nullam lobortis ante nec dictum elementum. Praesent aliquam orci quis molestie consectetur. Aliquam ornare a ipsum dapibus pulvinar. Morbi aliquet posuere ligula, vel volutpat dolor pellentesque vel. Vivamus non euismod leo. Duis feugiat velit a est tincidunt pulvinar. Proin blandit malesuada pulvinar. Nunc ut elementum ex, non vehicula tortor.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Change the height of your browser up and down to see how this works - the principle is a vertical flexbox that's at least the height of the screen, and a footer that's always at the bottom because the main content grows to fill any spare space.

Comment: Thank you very much. <3 I copied your approach into my file and it has some weird behaviour. The yellow footer is always displayed ~30 pixel out side of the bottom boundary. I will test it tomorrow further, maybe i made somewhere a mistake, i am not that skilled yet with html and css

Comment: As a workarround i could push it 30px upwards but thats kindy a dirty solution. Will test tomorrow more :)

Comment: Perhaps another CSS rule is overriding one of the above. Please could you post more of your code, so we can get a better idea of the context?

Comment: I put a striped down version of the sidebar here. Yes i think something must override it as i tested it with your code and some other code i found, see above, and it worked.  https://jsfiddle.net/testtesttest1/mx387paj/4/

Comment: Hi, I'm so glad it worked! Could you please accept my answer if it helped you? Many thanks in advance!